# How to prevent accidental unlocking?

Tags: security, lock-screen

I have a machine at work running tmux and xmonad that I lock with slock. I frequently need to ssh into it from a remote location, and, based on testing this in person, accidentally killing the slock process will inevitably lead to the ssh host unlocking and becoming suddenly accessible to anyone in the vicinity.

The ideal solution would be NOT to kill the slock process, but it's simply too easy to accidentally nuke a tmux window/pane running it or to kill it in some other way and completely forget to slock again afterwards.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a "safer" and more human-proof way of locking my machine, but still making it accessible through SSH. I haven't tested this extensively, but I suspect the same issue wouldn't occur if I was using Unity. Is there perhaps an slock alternative I could consider? Thoughts?